# l1=list and l2=list() declaration in python different?

Tags: python

Are the following declarations different?

```
l1=list
l2=list()
```

As I used *type()* function, following were the results!

```
type(l1)
<class 'type'>

type(l2)
<class 'list'>

l1 is l2
False
```

These probably shows that l1 and l2 are not the same. Why does l1 belongs to class type and not class list

Comment: `list` is not a call. `list()` is a call.

Comment: so what is l1=list doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are calling `list`, you get an instance of it class:

```
>> l = list()
>> l
[]
```

but when you assign `list` to another variable, you are completely transforming all `List` information to another variable and you can use them as you can use `List`, for example :

```
>> a = List
>> l1 = a() # same as l1 = List()
>> l1
[]
>> a
List
>> isinstance(l1, a)
True
>> isinstance(l1, List)
True
```

I hope this might helps you understand.

Answer (score 2):

`l1 = list` means assignment of `list` class in `l1` variable.

`l2=list()` mreans calling `list()` function to create a `list` and assign the list to `l2` variable.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, nothing gets called unless you ask for it to be called, with parentheses. Even if there are no arguments. Without the parentheses, you're just referring to the function, or method, or class, or whatever as a value. (This is different from some other languages, like Ruby or Perl.)

This may be a little more obvious with functions or methods:

```
>>> input
<function input>
>>> abs
<function abs>
>>> 'abc'.upper
<function str.upper>
```

… but it's exactly the same with classes:

```
>>> list
list
```

Those are all perfectly good values, which we can even store in a variable:

```
>>> abcupper = 'abc'.upper
```

---

When you call a function or method, you know what that does. When you call a class, that's how you construct an instance of the class.

Either way, you need the parentheses:

```
>>> abs(-2)
2
>>> list((1, 2, 3))
[1, 2, 3]
```

… even if there are no arguments:

```
>>> 'abc'.upper()
'ABC'
>>> list()
[]
```

… even if you're calling a method you stored in a variable earlier:

```
>>> abcupper()
'ABC'
```

Comment: _"In Python, nothing gets called unless you ask for it to be called, with parentheses"_ What about `print "Hello World!"` in Python 2.7?

Comment: @AGNGazer The `print` statement does not call the `print` function (or any other function) in Python 2.7.

Comment: @AGNGazer In particular, [here is the `print` function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Python/bltinmodule.c#L1580), and [here is the `PRINT_ITEM` bytecode handler](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Python/ceval.c#L1974). You can see that neither one calls each other. Or, more simply, just try replacing the `print` builtin, and then using a `print` statement; your code doesn't get called.

Comment: @AGNGazer I suppose technically, `print` does end up calling your object's `__str__` method, in the same way that `a + b` ends up calling `a.__add__` and/or `b.__radd__`, and in fact `f()` really just calls `f.__call__`… but I think getting into that would just make the answer more confusing rather than more helpful for anyone looking for help with an elementary question like this.

Comment: What about properties of objects (e.g., getters and setters)? Aren't these called without parenthesis?

Comment: @AGNGazer Not really. Look at [the pure Python version of `@property`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#properties): there's an explicit `self.fget(obj)` call. Of course the real `property` is in C rather than Python (at least in CPython), but that's the same as, say, `map(func, it)`. (Of course there _are_ implicit special-method calls to `obj.__getitem__`, `type(obj).__getitem__`, and `property.__get__`, but that's the same as the implicit calls to `__add__` and `__str__` and so on.)